# Router is not recieving JSON from model?

Tags: json, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to pass an object from a model to my route so I can finish my login system but I'm not recieving anything.

Model code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const config = require('../config/config.json');
var dynamoose = require('dynamoose');
const express = require('express');
var Schema = dynamoose.Schema;

const USER_SCHEMA = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  credential: {
    type: String
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

const USER = module.exports = dynamoose.model('Usuarios', USER_SCHEMA);

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function (user, callback) {
  var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  var params = {
    TableName: "Users",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#us = :uuuu",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#us": "username"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":uuuu": user
    }
  };
  docClient.query(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
      data.Items.forEach(function (user, callback) {
        console.log(user.username + ": " + user.password + user.email + user.firstName);
      });
    }
    callback(null, user);
  });
}
```

This is working fine, I can print user.username, user.password and so on, but for some reason my router is not importing the JSON

```
router.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;


  USER.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user) {
      return res.json({
        success: false,
        "msg": "User not found"
      });
    }
    USER.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (isMatch) {
        const token = jwt.sign({
          username: user
        }, secret.secret, {
          expiresIn: 86400
        });

        res.json({
          success: true,
          token: 'JWT ' + token,
          user: {
            user: user.username,
            password: USER.password,
            email: user.email
          }
        });
      } else {
        return res.json({
          success: false,
          msg: 'Wrong password'
        })
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The res.json from `comparePassword` should be the object from the route (which is the user model) but is not recieving a thing. I have tried with USER.username/email/etc user.username/email/etc but nothing works.
I know I must be missing something somewhere, but where?

Edit: Also tried with `module.export.user = user;` inside the model

Comment: does it send empty object upon POST request?

Comment: Yes, I post the username and password, compare the password, generate a jwt token and then I should recieve the object